# Построение маршрута с учётом пробок в заданное время yandex.maps.api

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Доброго времени суток.

Не так давно пришлось разобраться с yandex api. Просмотрев пару примеров с построением маршрутов и почитав справочник, не смог найти такой момент, как, построение маршрута с учётом пробок в заданное время. 
Максимум что удалось найти это - traffic.provider.Archive, но подменой timestamp ничего не решилось.

Подскажите, предоставляет ли yandex такую возможность?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В JavaScript API нет маршрутизации по прогнозу или статистике пробок. Эта функциональность доступна отдельно в составе [HTTP API Яндекс.Маршрутизации](https://tech.yandex.ru/routing/router/).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте включить статистику по пробкам (стандартный функционал API), а уже потом только строить маршрут. По идее маршрут как раз и должен строиться с учетом прогноза пробок

[image: Прогноз по пробкам]

Comment: Этот ползунок влияет только на отображаемый слой пробок (там действительно отображается статистика или прогноз), но не учитывается при построении маршрута.